# Require a function which specific names with extension and return specific names without extensions

Tags: function, sas

For example if a coulmn contains countries name like India7, Co. Canada, 162USA,4167India,Co.India , I want a function in SAS which returns India, Canada,USA,India, India respectively.

Comment: Look at the `compress` function with the `'d'` option... http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212246.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use prxchange. Try the below example

```
data abc;
var1='India7, Co. Canada, 162USA,4167India,Co.India';
var2=prxchange('s/[0-9 ]+|(co.)//i', -1, var1);
run;
```

here we can easily give  a pattern and substitute with ''.